# Compare SQL DB dates and add reference if dates match this date

Tags: jquery

I have SQL table where is StartDate, StopDate and Reference. How I can compare if today is between StartDate and StopDate and then return Reference from that row?

[image]

I have this function where dates are written directly to code and it works. I have ajax call to get rows from database, but how to add those rows to this function and how to find right Reference?

```
function getReferenceByDate() {

                    var startdate = ('04/18/2020'); // MM-DD-YYYY 
                    var stopdate= ('05/21/2020'); // MM-DD-YYYY 
                    var ref = ('REF')
                    var thisdate = new Date();

                    var start= Date.parse(startdate);
                    var stop= Date.parse(stopdate);
                    var now = Date.parse(thisdate);

                    if (now <= stop && now >= start) {
                    return ref;
                    }
                }
```

Ajax to get rows from DB

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/SeasonsAPI',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, season) {
                            getReferenceByDate(season);
                        })
                    }
                });-
```

I tried this, but it's not working

```
 var startdate = season.StartDate; 
 var stopdate = season.StopDate; 
 var ref = season.Reference;
```

EDIT: now function is working in console, but when I try to pass this variable, I get same "StartDate not defined"-error

```
var cart = {
                                            OrderID: sel.OrderID,
                                            CompanyID: sel.CompanyID,
                                            Orderdate: new Date(),
                                            ISBN: sel.ISBN,
                                            BookName: sel.BookName,
                                            Author: sel.Author,
                                            Publisher: sel.Publisher,
                                            Price: sel.Price,
                                            Season: sel.Season,
                                            IsInCart: false,
                                            SentToJvs: false,
                                            Reference: getReferenceByDate()  };
$.ajax({
                                                method: 'put',
                                                url: '/api/cartsAPI/' + cart.OrderID,
                                                data: JSON.stringify(cart),
                                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                                success: function () {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code and set the code based on your provided data and it's working fine for me so please review it and let me know if still any issue

```js
var matchGetReference = [];
function getReferenceByDate(season) {
        var startdate = season.StartDate; // MM-DD-YYYY 
        var stopdate= season.StopDate; // MM-DD-YYYY 
        var ref = season.Reference;
        var thisdate = new Date();

        var start= Date.parse(startdate);
        var stop= Date.parse(stopdate);
        var now = Date.parse(thisdate);

        if (now <= stop && now >= start) {
            return ref;
        }
    }
    var data = [{"$id":"1","SeasonID":1,"Season":"1/2020","StartDate":"2020-01-02","StopDate":"2020-06-25","Reference":"NV kevät 2020"},{"$id":"2","SeasonID":2,"Season":"2/2020","StartDate":"2020-07-01","StopDate":"2020-12-29","Reference":"NV syksy 2020"},{"$id":"3","SeasonID":3,"Season":"2/2019","StartDate":"2019-12-01","StopDate":"2019-12-10","Reference":"NV joulu1 2019"},{"$id":"4","SeasonID":4,"Season":"3/2019","StartDate":"2019-12-18","StopDate":"2019-12-31","Reference":"NV joulu2 2019"}] ;
    $.each(data, function (i, season) {
        var returnRef = getReferenceByDate(season)
        if (returnRef != undefined) {
          matchGetReference.push(returnRef);
        }
    });
if (matchGetReference[0] != undefined) {
console.log(matchGetReference[0]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A test</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    demo
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already but "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StartDate' of undefined" is error that I get. Maybe because dates from db are not in right form? If thats the case, how should I change that?

Comment: Problem looks like season object not contain the StartDate key so can you please provide the ajax api data and also console the season object and pass that object so i can validate from my end?

Comment: Api data [{"$id":"1","SeasonID":1,"Season":"1/2020","StartDate":"2020-01-02","StopDate":"2020-06-25","Reference":"NV kevät 2020"},{"$id":"2","SeasonID":2,"Season":"2/2020","StartDate":"2020-07-01","StopDate":"2020-12-29","Reference":"NV syksy 2020"},{"$id":"3","SeasonID":3,"Season":"2/2019","StartDate":"2019-12-01","StopDate":"2019-12-10","Reference":"NV joulu1 2019"},{"$id":"4","SeasonID":4,"Season":"3/2019","StartDate":"2019-12-18","StopDate":"2019-12-31","Reference":"NV joulu2 2019"}]

Comment: Console 'season': $id: "1", SeasonID: 1, Season: "1/2020", StartDate: "2020-01-02", StopDate: "2020-06-25", …}
$id: "1"
Reference: "NV kevät 2020"
Season: "1/2020"
SeasonID: 1
StartDate: "2020-01-02"
StopDate: "2020-06-25"  Thats first row

Comment: I have updated the code based on your data so please find this from my answer.
Also link is https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908709/11710118
Please let me know still you face any issue

Comment: Yes I can see it works in console, but when I'm trying to put that function into variable, it's still same error..  I put example in my question

Comment: Looks like you have not passed the row object into the Reference: getReferenceByDate() function so can you please pass that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: When you called this method getReferenceByDate() you have not passed any argument so you need to pass the season argument for getting the StartDate and StopDate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214281/discussion-between-heijoe-and-akash-prajapati).